# RDLC Report Error: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException

Tags: asp.net, report, runtime-error, rdlc

I have created an RDLC report and it works fine when I show the it in web browser. But my client now wants me to send PDF file to the browser/client instead of showing the report in web browser. I'm getting error when I added the code behind to create and send the report's PDF to the client/browser.
Here is my code to send PDF to the client/browser:

```
 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetData"
    TypeName="CourrierExpress.ExpressCourierDataSetTableAdapters.uspFrontEnd_Invoice_PrintInvoiceTableAdapter"
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="InvoiceId" QueryStringField="InvoiceId" Type="Int64"
            DefaultValue="" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I'm calling this code behind on Page Load:

```
 Int64 invoiceId = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["InvoiceId"]);
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamIds;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string extension;

        var rds = new ReportDataSource { DataSourceId = "ObjectDataSource1", Name = "DataSet1" };

        var viewer = new ReportViewer();
        viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports/ReportInvoicePrint.rdlc"; //This is your rdlc name.
        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        var bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension,
                                                 out streamIds, out warnings);

        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = mimeType;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= filename" + "." + extension);
        Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); // create the file  
        Response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download  
        Response.End();
```

RDLC report has Dataset named "DataSet1".
Error screenshot is:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Provide any other name for "Dataset1" example: "MyDataSourceName" and for datasource "StudentList" here is my datasource converted to list

```
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("MyDataSourceName", StudentList);
```

More info: http://forums.asp.net/t/1556522.aspx